# cant load asset from firebase storage to unity

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-storage, unitywebrequest

I am creating an augmented reality app using vuforia and unity. i have  uploaded my assetbundle to firebase storage and i want to retrieve a 3d model saved inside it and load it as a child on my image target game object but it i cant retrieve it.i also installed firebase unity sdk.

```c#
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Storage;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class loadmodel2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject test;

    void Start()
    {
        FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance;

        Firebase.Storage.StorageReference reference =storage.GetReferenceFromUrl("gs://fit-union-221609.appspot.com/assettest1/myasset");

        reference.GetDownloadUrlAsync().ContinueWith((Task<Uri> task) => {
            if (!task.IsFaulted && !task.IsCanceled)
            {
                Debug.Log("Download URL: " + task.Result);
                // ... now download the file via WWW or UnityWebRequest.
                StartCoroutine(Loadcoroutine());
            }
        });
    }

    IEnumerator Loadcoroutine()
    {
        string url = "gs://fit-union-221609.appspot.com/assettest1/myasset";
        WWW www = new WWW(url);
        while (!www.isDone)
            yield return null;
        AssetBundle myasset = www.assetBundle;

        GameObject mya1 = myasset.LoadAsset("Barbarian Variant") as GameObject;

        Instantiate(mya1).transform.parent = test.transform;
    }
}
```

[image: this is what i want]

**i created a new asset bundle with the same name "myasset" and uploaded it to firebase storage ialso changed the name of the 3d model to "BarbarianVariant" removing the space**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**in here i have enabled loadmodel2 script in the main camera and for the test game object i assigned maincamera.you can also see the output i get in the console**

Answer (score 1):

First of all your component `loadmodel2` is disabled in the Inspector so its `Start` will never be called ...

---

I'm no Firebase expert but you first use `GetDownloadUrlAsync` and then anyway never use the result but start a new `UnityWebRequest` for downloading it from the same reference URL.

Don't you rather want to use the retrieved download URL from `task.Result` like e.g.

```c#
StartCoroutine(Loadcoroutine(task.Result));

...

IEnumerator Loadcoroutine(Uri uri)
{
    ...
}
```

---

Then note that **[`WWW`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html)(obsolete) != [`UnityWebRequest`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html)!**

What you want to do is probably rather using [`UnityWebRequestAssetBundle.GetAssetBundle`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequestAssetBundle.GetAssetBundle.html) (or in former versions [`UnityWebRequest.GetAssetBundle`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-DownloadingAssetBundle.html))

```c#
IEnumerator Loadcoroutine(Uri uri)
{
    using(var www = UnityWebRequestAssetBundle.GetAssetBundle(uri))
    {
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if(www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError) 
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else 
        {
            AssetBundle bundle = DownloadHandlerAssetBundle.GetContent(www);

            // Make sure this path is correct! Afaik it should at least start with "Assets/..."
            var mya1 =  bundle.LoadAssetAsync<GameObject>("Barbarian Variant");
            yield return mya1;

            var obj = Instantiate((GameObject)mya1.asset);
            obj.transform.parent = test.transform;
        }
    }
}
```

In general I would also avoid spaces in `GameObject` names.

Comment: tnx for the reply but i get an error saying i cant convert task.result from system.uri to string

Comment: Yeah my bad .. I notes later that it is a `Task<Uri>` updated the answer.

Comment: i get an error in transform saying  object does not contain a defenition for transform and no accesible extension method transform accepting a first argument of type object could be found but even if that line of code is removed it should download my model from firebase right but its not getting downloaded

Comment: Sorry I'm typing only on the phone ;) You have to cast the returned `Object` to `GameObject`. Either like `var obj = Instantiate((GameObject)mya1.asset);` or `var obj = (GameObject) Instantiate (mya1.asset);` should be the same afaik. How exactly do you track the download? Do you get any errors? Did you try debugging the code step by step?

Comment: well this is the output i get on the console-Download URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fit-union-221609.appspot.com/o/assettest1%2Fmyasset?alt=media&token=2e486742-add0-40e9-ada0-83e6e5cc7195
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
Loadmodel2:<Start>b__1_0(Task`1) (at Assets/Loadmodel2.cs:25)
System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback:PerformWaitCallback()

Comment: i get the download url in the debug but nothing gets instantiated or downloaded

Comment: can someone please help me on this this is my final year project

Comment: i debugged each line of code but couldnt find any errors

Comment: Can you make sure your path for `LoadAssetAsync` is correct? Usually afaik it should at least begin with `"Assets/..."`

Comment: so bro i posted more information if that helps u ,and should my path for the load asset async be "myasset/BarbarianVariant" i tried it but that didnt work.i also used tried using your code to download from a local file system(path in my pc)and it worked fine.

Comment: The path has to match your prefab names and folder structure within the Asset bundle -> the one it had in Unity when building the Asset bundle.